# Websocket STOMP (or REST) Controller in Spring: capture deserialization error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket, spring-restcontroller

I have a Spring Websocket Stomp controller that handles SEND messages (similarly to https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) :

```
@MessageMapping("/pong")
public void handlePong(IncomingModel model) {...}
```

It works fine if my IncomingModel can be deserializes behind-the-scenes correctly.

If it is however not the case, I receive something like

```
2017-02-21 11:24:31.935 ERROR 12536 --- [nboundChannel-3] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler :
Unhandled exception from message handler method
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException:
Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Long from String "2017-02-21T09:24:31.917Z": not a valid Long value
```

How I can capture this error in my code and handle it? 
I suppose the case is the same as with REST controllers.

Comment: Show your JSON?

Comment: It is a simple Json where string is sent in place of long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `@MessageExceptionHandler(MessageConversionException.class)` annotation on method to handle `MessageConversionException`. Or annotation `@MessageExceptionHandler()` without parameters to handle any exception.

Comment: Should the above be placed in the controller class only or in ControllerAdvice ?